# Suppress SQL Queries logging in Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, serilog

I have a console .net core app that uses entity framework core.
The app uses logging framework to write to file and console:

```
 serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging()
        .AddDbContext<DataStoreContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    //configure console logging
    serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
        .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)
        .AddSerilog();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logs/vcibot-{Date}.txt"))
        .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logs/vcibot-errors-{Date}.txt"), LogEventLevel.Error)
        .CreateLogger();

    logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
        .CreateLogger<Program>();
```

Min Level for file output is set to Information. But with this setup output also contains SQL queries, here is the example:

> 2017-02-06 10:31:38.282 -08:00 [Information] Executed DbCommand (0ms)
>   [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT
>   [f].[BuildIdentifier], [f].[Branch], [f].[BuildDate],
>   [f].[StaticAssetSizeInKb] FROM [FileSizesHistoryEntries] AS [f]

Is there a way to disable the SQL queries logging  (log them only in Debug log level)

Comment: I know this is old, but where did you get `Configuration` from in your code?

Comment: Many of those EF Core log statements should have be coded/leveled at debug, and not info.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Don't know if this is still an active question, but this is my solution, override the minimum level for "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command"

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(loggingLevelSwitch)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("app", environment.ApplicationName)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile($"./Logs/{environment.ApplicationName}")
            .CreateLogger();
```

you can also have this on the appconfig.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:u}] [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails" ]
  }
```

Comment: Is there possibility to specify this ```MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command"``` thing in appsettings file?

Comment: Hi @AkmalSalikhov, please check my edited answer. Regards.

Comment: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model": "Warning"
Did it for me. You can see in the logs what you need to override.

Comment: This should not be needed. You already set the `Microsoft` prefix to warning. That should include `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command`.

Answer (score 82):

Found that if Logging section is modified in following manner i am not see EF logs message related to SQL queries:

```json
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

Comment: For disabling SQL command trace this is by far the best and simplest answer.

Comment: worked immediately, stopped seeing all the EF log for each select statement

Comment: logging.AddFilter was not working for me in the Blazor server project, but this approach worked

Comment: Only the last line is required right? What is the point of setting the other namespaces too?

Comment: @Wolfware, just for understanding where this line is located

Answer (score 74):

If you're using built-in logger, you can add filter to you ILoggingBuilder in Program.cs.

So, it can look like:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    // ...
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => {
        var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
        var config = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
        // ...
        logging.AddConfiguration(config);
        logging.AddConsole();
        // ...
        logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);
    })
    // ...
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: If you want to disable all logging from certain categories, just set the `LogLevel` to `LogLevel.Critical + 1` instead of just `LogLevel.Warning`

Comment: If you use `LogLevel.None` its value is 6, so no logging.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using the default Logger, in the `appsettings.json` (or `appesttings.Development.json` for dev startup) file:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"        <----
    }
},
```

Set it to `Warning` instead of `Information`.

Comment: That's for the Microsoft Default Logger, not Serilog.

Answer (score 8):

You want to change your Serilog configuration to set the minimum level for the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory` context to `Warning` or higher.

You can find the context you need to change by setting the output template to something like `[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}`. Once you know the context you can set the template back to how it was before.

Comment: I've managed to exclude the context/source completely:
`.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory"))`

but don't know how to set minimum level

Comment: If you're doing your configuration from code, you should be able to do something like `new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Information().MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory", LogEventLevel.Warning)`? I usually configure this from Serilog.Settings.Configuration JSON: `{"Serilog": {"MinimumLevel": {"Default": "Information", "Override": {"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory": "Warning"}}}}`

Comment: Those details added much practical value to the answer.
I've tried it from code and it works. Thanks! I will try JSON config later and for sure it is preferred way as you have external control on logging options.

Comment: One very strange thing is that copy-pasted code didn't worked till I've found that there are some invisible characters in the string literal (I had to type it by hand to work; I think it is stack overflow issue?).

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue in one of my projects and noticed that there's a bit more to look at in addition to earlier answers to this question.

You can do things like this:

```json
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": true,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning" <-- Note that this applies to EF Core, including everything in it.
        }
    }
```

What's also important is the order where things are added to the `ILoggingBuilder`.

```cs
    // This still will log EF messages to the console.
    serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
        builder
            .AddConsole()
            .AddConfiguration(config.GetSection("Logging")));

    // This will apply the configuration to the console logger.
    serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
        builder
            .AddConfiguration(config.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddConsole());
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers doesn't work for me then i found this one:

On your Programs.cs, creating builder, add that line:

`builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);`

Answer (score 0):

First find your source context where sql queries are being generated from. To do that, set **outputTemplate** as described [here](https://hovermind.com/serilog/class-name-method-name-and-line-number.html).

Then add it in LoggerConfiguration

```
.MinimumLevel.Override(<your_source_context>, LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

Answer (score -1):

1.First I have installed these two Nuget packages.

[image]

2.Configurations goes like this

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)    
            .WriteTo.File(builder.Environment.WebRootPath + "/Logs/SUPCOMS-LOG-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
        
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

3.Log writing looks like this

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
    private readonly SupcomsDBContext _dBContext;
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass(SupcomsDBContext dBContext, ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        this._dBContext = dBContext;
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public bool MyMethod()
    { 
      _logger.LogError("I have an error");
      _logger.LogInformation("This is an information"  );
    }
}
```

4.Log file looks like this

[image]

Comment: How is it working? Is it this line `builder.Logging.ClearProviders();` ?